# Can Arcmap 10 do change detection?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, feature-layer, change-detection

I have an assignment to find out changed areas of the two different layers ( let's say 2000 and 2010).the layers are vector. Is it possible to detect the changed areas by using Arcgis?

Comment: Do you mean changed areas between two layers (rather than maps)?  If so, are your layers raster or vector?  When you answer please do so by editing your question rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ArcGIS, it is simple to basic change detection between two raster surfaces using the [raster calculator](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/How_Raster_Calculator_works/009z000000z8000000/).
[Here](http://www.joewheaton.org/Home/research/software/GCD/2010-nsf-lidar-workshop-materials) are some excerpts of simple exercises from a change detection seminar at the NSF Sponsored Workshop on "New Tools in Process-Based Analysis of Lidar Topographic Data".  For more advanced change detection software and techniques, see [GCD](http://gcd.joewheaton.org/) Software. At version 10.1 you can use Using the [Difference button](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_the_Difference_button_on_the_Image_Analysis_window/009t000000n4000000/) on the Image Analysis window extention.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the union tool to create individual polygons of the two  feature classes. Then use the attribute fields to select those areas that are exclusive to area 1 and/or exclusive to area 2.